# Cocoa: Implementing a welcome screen with multiple pages guiding user through use and settings of the application

Tags: cocoa, macos

What is the correct way to go about **creating a welcome window for a first-time user that has multiple pages of information and settings that the user can hit "Next" through**, to get oriented with and perform an initial setup of the app before using it? Is there something I can use in Interface Builder for this purpose?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no built-in support for this, but basically, you just have a user default that you check when the app finishes launching. If it's not set, you set it and then invoke your first-run behavior. For a window with multiple "pages" of information, the simplest approach is to simply have a tab view with the tabs hidden, where each page is a tab view item's view.

Comment: Am I supposed to use "Tabless"? And if I do, then how do I edit each tab in Interface Builder?

Comment: @Chetan: I find the simplest way is to use the list or column view mode in Interface Builder. It makes it pretty simple to select subviews very precisely.